# C retrive the boot settings/options in windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, boot, bcdedit

I would like to know how can I get the similar info from bcdedit.exe with C and win32 api.
Is it possible? or should I use the system command and write the log to a file:
bcdedit.exe > blaa.txt ?

Comment: Haven't gotten into this area, but [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362675(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: It might be helpful but I'm writing in C, so I cannot use classes..

Comment: I don't know if there's anything else in there for C, but at least it's a possibility if there's a method without too much to get it going.

Comment: You can use WMI with C, via COM.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx unfortunately the examples are in C++ but you can use C instead.